# Mongodb update field inside object array with one condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I have the following field inside my mongo documents

```
"offers" : [ 
        {
            "price" : 15,
            "Date1" : 1661385600000.0,
            "fullname" : "name 1",
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "createdDate" : 1660660090798.0,
            "expired" : false
        },
        {
            "price" : 40,
            "Date1" : 1661388600000.0,
            "fullname" : "name 2",
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "createdDate" : 1660660090788.0,
            "expired" : false
        }
    ],
```

And I want to map all the objects inside the array of all documents in the DB and compare the field  `createdDate` with the current date, if this comparison is true, I want to change the `expired` field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was use [updateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method and in the update param I used [$exist](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) [$ne](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) and [$lt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators to make the logic.

And the code was the following:

```
let today = new Date();
let twoDayAgo = today.setDate(today.getDate()-2); //subtracting 2 days from today's date
let orderCriteria = {
    orderStatus  : "STATUS_THAT_I_WHANT_TO_FIND",
    offers       : { $exists: true, $ne: [] },//if find the order by status, proving that the key offers exist and is not empty
    isDeleted    : false,
    "offers.createdDate" : { $lt: twoDayAgo } //compares the value with twoDaysAgo variable
  };
let data2Updat = {
    $set: {
          "offers.$.expired" : true
        } 
    }
let result = await DAOManager.updateMany( Model, orderCriteria, data2Updat, {} )
```